# Iterator semantics for class with wrapped C functions and no container data

Tags: c++, oop, iterator

I have a RAII-managed class which uses functions from a C library. Their signature usually is:

```
int get_next_data(handle_type* handle, struct struct_type** output_param);
```

and return success/failure status or end of file/data flag.

Function `get_next_data()` uses `malloc()` internally to allocate memory for `struct_type` and writes a pointer to that memory in `output_param`.

I'm trying to implement iterator semantics for that class but there is no structure to iterate over or to increment; just incoming values until exhaustion (number of values is unknown), denoted by a flag.

Is there a way to implement `T* begin()` and `T* end()` methods in such a way so that the underlying resource could be iterated over? What these methods should return? Should they be implemented? Is there an alternate solution?

I looked at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) but haven't found what I need. Is there a type of iterators like this: `std::iterator(begin, end, some_func, stop_predicate);` or `std::iterator(some_func, stop_predicate);`? If there is, how to return the output parameter so that it would be accessible to the iterator?

The class has data members a vector `data_vec` and pointer to a C `struct` `handle`. The C library calls are abstracted by the class interface. In the current implementation there is a `void C::read()` method which is called after construction by the client code to populate the vector:

```
void C::read() {
    struct_type* current_elem = nullptr;

    while(get_next_data(handle, &current_elem) == SUCCESS) { 
        struct_type* data_ptr = copy_data(current_elem); // heap allocation

        data_vec.push_back(data_ptr);
    }
}
```

Function `copy_data()` provided by the same library is used to pull (copy) the data struct from internally allocated storage which is overwritten on next iteration.

Currently I'm working on workaround for reading `current_elem` directly to `data_vec` avoiding unnecessary copying and wasting clock cycles.

Example usage:

```
int main() {
    C c;
    c.read();

    // iteration on data_vec

}
```

Comment: Read the [InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) requirements and write a class conforming to them. Look at [`istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) for inspiration. *"What these methods should return?"* Both return objects of your iterator class. `.begin()` reads one value, stores it into an iterator. The iterator then reads the next value when `++` is called on it. `.end()` returns just a null/empty iterator (`==` must return true when comparing it with a EOF-ed iterator).

Comment: "*`int get_next_data(handle_type* handle, struct struct_type* output_param);` ... uses `malloc()` internally to allocate memory for `struct_type` and writes a pointer to that memory in `output_param`.*" - then you have a memory leak, because that signature can't return the pointer back to you. It would need to be `int get_next_data(handle_type* handle, struct_type** output_param)` instead, and then you could call it like: `struct_type* current_elem = nullptr; while (get_next_data(handle, &current_elem) == SUCCESS) { ... free(current_elem); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry, it was mistake on my end. Fixed the code in edit. The allocation cleanup is done by the destructor (forgot to mention it), traversing and calling `free()` on each element of the vector. Checked by `-fsanitize=leak` on `clang++`.

Comment: In that case, this seems like a pretty straight forward task. Either you call your `Read()` method and then provide iterators into your `vector`, or you create a custom `iterator` that calls `get_next_data()` and `copy_data()` on each call to its `operator++` until `get_next_data()` doesn't have any more data to provide.